# Access an arrays item prop value with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of div blocks and I am trying to access the innerHTML of the "time" tag for each one. How can I access this value?

```
<div class="review-full-review-single-review-wrap">
    <span class="review-full-timestamp">
        <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2015-07-29T11:25:47-07:00">July 29, 2015</time>
    </span>
    <p class="review-camo-rewards">Reward points earned</p>
</div>

<div class="review-full-review-single-review-wrap">
    <span class="review-full-timestamp">
        <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2015-07-29T11:25:47-07:00">July 1, 2015</time>
    </span>
    <p class="review-camo-rewards">Reward points earned</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("review-full-review-single-review-wrap")
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var timeElems = elems[i].getElementsByTagName("time");
    for (var j = 0; j < timeElems.length; j++) {
        console.log(timeElems[j].innerHTML)
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q311LcL3/

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll("div time");

for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    alert(blocks[i].innerHTML);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f9j6xzm0/

Answer (score 0):

When you need to work with TagName the best choice is to use `getElementsByTagName`

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('time');
var dbg = document.getElementById('dbg');
  

dbg.innerHTML = "<hr> result  : <br>"

 for(var i=0 ; i < list.length ; i++ ){
   
   var cur = list[i];
   
   console.log( cur.innerHTML );
   
   dbg.innerHTML += '<br>' + cur.innerHTML;
 }
```

```html
<div class="review-full-review-single-review-wrap">
    <span class="review-full-timestamp">
        <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2015-07-29T11:25:47-07:00">July 29, 2015</time>
    </span>
    <p class="review-camo-rewards">Reward points earned</p>
</div>

<div class="review-full-review-single-review-wrap">
    <span class="review-full-timestamp">
        <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2015-07-29T11:25:47-07:00">July 1, 2015</time>
    </span>
    <p class="review-camo-rewards">Reward points earned</p>
</div>

<div id='dbg'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use **forEach**.

```
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".review-full-timestamp time");
blocks.forEach(function (elem) {
    alert(elem.textContent);
});
```

A word of caution about the **time** element, it isn't widely supported yet.  Ref: http://caniuse.com/#search=time